# Office js - Word Desktop vs Online Tables discrepancy

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In Word Online I'm seeing tables can be inserted directly after one another in the document without creating a paragraph element between.

The Office JS API in Word Online outputs these as two separate table objects in a table collection. However when the same document is accessed through the Desktop they appear to merge into a single table object.

When viewing the range ooxml, the two tables are formatted as though it is one.

Word Online:
[image]

Word for Windows:
[image: Office JS Desktop]

It can be seen by inserting two tables after another in Word, logging the selected range, and looking at the table collections property.

```
const context = await this.run();
const rangeObject = context.document.getSelection();
rangeObject.load('tables');
await context.sync();
console.log(rangeObject);
```

Which of these instances is the intended behaviour?

Comment: I am assuming the inserting table operation is through UI, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: The desktop behavior is the "expected" or "intended" one, as far as the Word object models are concerned. The desktop version has existed since the late 1980's; Word On-line only a couple of years... Word On-line 1) does not support the full extent of the Word desktop functionality and 2) does a number of things differently ("wrongly", from the view-point of the full application capability)...

Comment: .... I have no idea whether this is particular thing is intentional or an oversight during its development. Word uses the paragraph between tables to store important information concerning the table - whether text-wrap formatting can be used, for example. Word on-line does *not* support text wrap around tables, so the lack of requiring the paragraph between tables might be explained by that. A document with a "floating" table lays out quite differently in the on-line version, but the "floating" is retained when the document is again opened in the desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known discrepancy in behavior between Word for Windows and Word Online, and as it does not currently cause any particularly bad experiences, Word Online doesn't currently have any solid plans to "fix" this discrepancy. Word Online simply just considers them two different tables.

In the future, if we did feel the need to address this discrepancy in experience, we would likely just align Word Online more closely with the desktop experience by disabling the ability to create a table immediately after another table.

Comment: Thanks @leeviana-gray,

The reason I asked is because we are developing an Add-In that relies on the inner elements of a content control to be consistent in order for us to know if we need to "repair" those elements.